# nodemon sometimes not working on my node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I'm using nodemon on my node.js app to restart the server on its own for any change made.

I just made some changes on one of the route file and it gave me 404 error so I thought something must went wrong with my code but when I opened it on a new browser window or restarted Terminal, it worked fine with the changed code.

Has anyone experienced this with nodemon and perhaps can share a solution?

Comment: what happens when you enter "nodemon server.js" does it give an error then? if it does can you put a picture of the error?

Comment: When I get 404 on browser, I don't get any error in Terminal when running "nodemon server.js" 
`7 Oct 22:45:18 - [nodemon] 1.7.1
7 Oct 22:45:18 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter rs
7 Oct 22:45:18 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
7 Oct 22:45:18 - [nodemon] starting node ./bin/www server.js`

Comment: Did you solved this problem? I got same problem.

Answer (score 0):

nodemon by default watches only few of the extension i.e only in some of the file you make changes it gets restarted. If you are using any other extension in your file you can always try
nodemon app.js -e js,hbs

assuming -
 app.js is your main file name
-e: stands for extension
js and hbs are file extension like app.js/header.hbs